# Vanilla JS Hide/show DIV toggler

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to implement a way to display / hide a div element with vanilla JavaScript triggered by a click event. The hide function works well but I seem to be missing something important when it comes to displaying the div's again. I've verified that the toggler function is working.

Simple sandbox here:
https://codepen.io/pen/eYmOzVe

```js
(function() {
    "use strict";

    // HTML References
    var flags = document.querySelector(".flags");

    // Toogle
    var toogle = true;

    // Flag object
    var flagObject = {
        init: function(part1, part2, part3, part4, part5) {
            this.part1 = part1;
            this.part2 = part2;
            this.part3 = part3;
            this.part4 = part4;
            this.part5 = part5;
        },
        draw: function() {
            flags.innerHTML += `
            <div id="${this.part1}">
            <div class="${this.part2}">
            <div class="${this.part3}"></div>
            <div class="${this.part4}"></div>
            <div class="${this.part5}"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            `;
        },
        toogler: function(arg) {
            toogle ? flagObject.remove(arg) : flagObject.show(arg);
            toogle = !toogle;
        },
        remove: function(arg) {
            if (arg == "1") {
                flag1Element.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
            if (arg == "2") {
                flag2Element.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        },
        show: function(arg) {
            if (arg == "1") {
                flag1Element.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
            if (arg == "2") {
                flag2Element.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
    };

    // Create instances of the object
    var swedishFlag = Object.create(flagObject);
    var japaneseFlag = Object.create(flagObject);

    // Init
    swedishFlag.init(
        "flag1",
        "flag-sweden",
        "cross-one-sweden",
        "cross-two-sweden"
    );
    japaneseFlag.init("flag2", "flag-japan", "circle-japan");

    // Array containing all flags
    var allObjects = [swedishFlag, japaneseFlag];

    // Draws flags
    for (let i = 0; i < allObjects.length; i++) {
        allObjects[i].draw();
    }

    // HTML element refrences
    var flag1Element = document.querySelector("#flag1");
    var flag2Element = document.querySelector("#flag2");

    // Add eventlisteners to remove flags on click
    flag1Element.addEventListener("click", function() {
        flagObject.toogler(1);
    });

    flag2Element.addEventListener("click", function() {
        flagObject.toogler(2);
    });
})();
```

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    color: green;
}

.content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 2em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 800px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.flags {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 1000px;
}

.flag-sweden {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #006aa7;
    height: 200px;
    width: 320px;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.cross-one-sweden {
    background-color: #fecc00;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0;
    left: 100px;
}

.cross-two-sweden {
    background-color: #fecc00;
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0;
}

.flag-japan {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 320px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.circle-japan {
    background-color: #bd0029;
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -62.5px 0 0 -62.5px;
}
```

```html
        <h1>Sandbox</h1>
        <div id="content" class="content">
            <div class="flags"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: After you make it hidden the element is not clickable, so there is no event that can be triggered, are you able to add a button to manually add the element?

Comment: Side note; rather than creating a secondary variable to keep track of if the variable is shown/hidden, create a class that hides the element and toggle that class on and off the classList.  The (non)existance of the class on the object becomes both your functionality and your state.  No need for a secondary variable to reflect the dom state.

Comment: I guess a solution instead of hiding the div would be to just change the div's css style to have the same background color as of the body, making it appear as if it's "hidden".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pavlin Petkov said in the comments, the image is not clickable when you hide it, so you can't toggle it back on. A simple solution to this that achieves the same result is to change the opacity instead of the visibility:

```
remove: function(arg) {
  if (arg == "1") {
    flag1Element.style.opacity = 0;
  }
  if (arg == "2") {
    flag2Element.style.opacity = 0;
  }
},
show: function(arg) {
  if (arg == "1") {
    flag1Element.style.opacity = 1;
  }
  if (arg == "2") {
    flag2Element.style.opacity = 1;
  }
}
```

This will display/hide a div with a click effect, and it will continue to occupy space on the page, as in your codepen. If you *need* to use `visibility` for some reason, I'd recommend a container div beneath the now hidden div which can trigger the show function; however, for the question at hand, this is sufficient.

Comment: This seems to be the easiest solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks. Generally, I use JS to apply/remove a CSS class that gives me the effects I want. This makes it easy to change the styles that are active for a given state. This is useful for things like animation, position, display, visibility, background color... the nice thing with this pattern is that it's pretty easy to update if you need more complex CSS later on. This is basically what Taplar recommended in the comments on your original question.